Unity Photon IsMine проблема с камерой
Пытаюсь сделать мультиплеерный шутер от первого лица с помощью Unity и Photon Network(PUN) и появилась проблема. Руки игроков прикреплены к камере дочерним объектом (для "Осмотра с помощью мыши"), если использовать isMine, то игроки не видят оружия в руках противников. Если isMine не использовать, то в игре остается одна камера на всех игроков. Может что-то нужно добавить или предложите решение без isMine.
public class PlayerSetup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Movement movement;

    public GameObject _camera;

    [SerializeField] private PhotonView _photonview;

    private void Start()
    {
        _camera.SetActive(_photonview.IsMine);
    }

    public void isLocalPlayer()
    {
            movement.enabled = true;
            _camera.SetActive(true);
    }

}

